# If $abc\neq 0$, then at least one of $ax^2+2bx+c$, $bx^2+2cx+a$, $cx^2+2ax+b$ has root

Tags: contest-math

> Prove that if $abc\neq 0$ then at least one of the equations $ax^2+2bx+c$, $bx^2+2cx+a$, $cx^2+2ax+b$ has root.

Source: All-Russian Math Olympiad 1994.

**My sketch of proof:** The condition $abc\neq 0$ is equivalent to $a,b,c\neq 0$.

Suppose that none of these equation have root. Then we have the following three inequalities: $b^2-ac<0, c^2-ab<0, a^2-bc<0.$ Adding all these three inequalities we get: $a^2+b^2+c^2<ab+ac+bc$. But we can easily show that $a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab+bc+ac$ which leads to contradiction.

However, this approach seems to me quite weird because I have not used the condition that $abc\neq 0.$

After some time I got the correct solution which is the following: Since $b^2<ac, c^2<ab, a^2<bc$  we get that $(abc)^2<(abc)^2$ and with $abc\neq 0$ this leads to contradiction.

But what's wrong with my approach?

Comment: $a,b,c\neq 0$ is just a condition that makes sure the three expressions ARE quadratic.

Comment: root = **real** root?

Comment: @RobertIsrael, sure!

Comment: @Mick, so what?

Comment: @ZFR If a = 0, what will $ax^2+2bx+c$ become? Will it be quadratic still?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have used $abc\ne0$. Out of that condition, say $a=0$ you don't have quadratic equation $$ax^2+bx+c=0$$ so you can't say $b^2-ac<0$

Answer (score 1):

If one or two of $a,b,c$ are zero, one of the equations is linear and has a root.  If they are all zero, they all are the zero polynomial and all have roots at all $x$.  Your assumption that all three do not have a root includes the assumption that they are all nonzero.

Comment: More formally: if at least one of them is zero then one of them has a root. By contrapositive: If none of them have a root then none of them is zero which is equivalent to $abc\neq 0$. Right? I guess that's what you meant.